# Java to Beanshell: validate an attribute for each record of a spreadsheet

Tags: java

Suppose this Java code is converted to Beanshell and called by an application which reads a spreadsheet and validates the department of each employee at a university.

My primary concern is if there is a more efficient, standard, or otherwise better way to go about validating an employee's department rather than how I have done so below.  Null should be returned if the department is invalid.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test{

    public static final String VALID_DEPARTMENTS[] = {
            "Computer Science", "Biology"
    };

    public static final HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>( Arrays.asList(VALID_DEPARTMENTS) );

    public String validate(String dep) {
        if( set.contains(dep) )
            return dep; 
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println( t.validate("CS") );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things come to mind:

1. In Java 9 one can use `Set.of("X", "Y", ...)`.
2. Or could simplify to `private static final Set<String> VALID_DEPARTMENTS = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));`
3. Could modify validate(dep) to `return set.contains(dep) ? dep : null;`
4. It would be nice to return `""` instead of null if at all possible.  This is so that a project won't end up with tons of `if (x != null)` all over the place.
5. Recommend renaming `Test` to something more descriptive.  Maybe `DepartmentValidator` might be a step in the right direction.
6. Probably refactor `dep` to `department`.  Eventually the meaning may become less obvious as time passes and the code base grows larger.
7. Note: the validation is currently quite strict (exact match), so I'm assuming the incoming data is pretty exact (no misspellings or different capitalization, etc.)